# Number of elements of the nth power set of the empty set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let n be a natural number find #℘ⁿ(∅) where ℘ⁿ means the n-th power set.

I know that it has 2ⁿ where n is the number of elements. Other than this I don't know where to start should I assign S={∅} and #℘ⁿ(S) and use Cantor's theorem?

Comment: It should be pretty obvious after doing the first few. $2^0, 2^{2^0},...$

Comment: so 2^(2^(n)) elements?

Comment: No. Find it out for e.g. $n=1,2,3,4$ and have a good look.

Comment: n=1 #=1, n=2 #=2, n=3 #=8, n=4 #=16?

Comment: If $a_n:=|\wp^n(\emptyset)|$ then $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=2^{a_n}$. That does *not* lead to $a_n=2^{2^n}$ as you suggest.

Comment: I sort of see the pattern I just can't put my finger on it, I mean from the first comment I see that it just stacks 2^(2^(0)) on top of each other I just cant visualize the end

Comment: $1,2^1=2,2^2=4,2^4=16,2^{16}=65536,2^{65536}=2.003529930...10^{19728},...$ You can't imagine how big the next is. Exceeds a Googolplex by far.

Comment: so how do I describe this phenomenon, I forgot how to create a sequence given the first term.

Comment: Welcome to tetration. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: But none of this was covered in the class. The textbook shows a decision tree and then concludes that the number of elements is 2^(2^(2^2^2...2^(2^(0)) where there is n is number of 2s

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1$ we have $\mathcal |P(\emptyset)|=2^0=1$.

For $n=2$ we have $\mathcal |P^2(\emptyset)|=2^{|\mathcal P(\emptyset)|}=2^1=2$.

Writing the final answer as a closed form might not be so easy without the proper notation. You could do it with ellipsis and proper explanation or another special notation, [Knuth's Up-Arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) is one way. After $n=2$ it will be easy to see how.

For $n=3$ we have $\mathcal |P^3(\emptyset)|=2^{|\mathcal P^2(\emptyset)|}=2^{2}$.

For $n=4$ we have $\mathcal |P^4(\emptyset)|=2^{|\mathcal P^3(\emptyset)|}=2^{2^{2}}$.

$\vdots$

For general $n>1$, $\displaystyle \mathcal |P^n(\emptyset)|=2^{2^{.^{.^{.^2}}}}$ where there are $(n-1)$ $2'$s. In Knuth's notation, this is: $2 \uparrow\uparrow (n-1)$.

Comment: We haven't learned Knuth's notation in our class is it possible to describe it using a geometric sequence or series?

Comment: drhab gave you a good way to describe it using a sequence. this is not a geometric sequence, it some steps beyond. It increases incredibly fast. $\mathcal P^6(\emptyset)$ has about $10^{20,000}$ elements, many, many, many times the number of electrons in the universe.